# Convergence of probability distributions of the distance between two uniformly distributed points on a n-sphere for $n\to\infty$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

We define the $(n-1)$-sphere as $\Bbb S^{n-1}:=\{x\in\Bbb R^n : \|x\|_2=1\}$.
Let be $X_n,Y_n$ random vector independent and identically uniformly distributed on $\Bbb S^n$ and define $Z_n:=\|X_n-Y_n\|_2$ (Euclidean distance in $\Bbb R^{n+1}$ between $X_n$ and $Y_n$).

I'm not able to calculate the probability measure of $Z_n$ rigorously for all $n$ (even for $n=1$ this isn't really pleasant), but I've simulated it (histograms in python) for dimensions up to one million and the probability measures of $Z_n$ seems to converge (weakly) to $\delta_\sqrt{2}$ (the Dirac measure to $\sqrt{2}$) for $n\to\infty$ which fairly surprised me.

Does somebody know or has any idea of a proof or a related result? Are the probability measures of $Z_n$ known explicitly? Is there an accessible intuition why distances concentrate around $\sqrt 2$ in very high dimensions? Maybe there a reasonable extension to infinite dimensions?

---

For the sake of completeness, I will give the (python 3) code of my simulation and some results are given in the following image: [image: Results of simulation]

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def n_sphere_unif(n):
    x = np.random.normal(0,1,n+1) # centered Gaussian iid
    return x/np.linalg.norm(x) # zero is very unlikely
def make_hist(dim, runs=20000):
    d = np.zeros(runs)
    for i in range(runs):
        d[i] = np.linalg.norm(n_sphere_unif(dim)-n_sphere_unif(dim))
    return plt.hist(d, bins=100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By symmetry one of your points might as well be $X_n=(1,0,0,\ldots,0)$.  The other can be $Y_n= (z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_n)/R$ where the $z_i$ are iid $N(0,1)$ random variables and $R=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n z_i^2}$.  The squared  distance $\|X_n-Y_n\|^2 = 2-2z_1/R^2$.  The random variable $z_1$ is tight, and the random variable $R^2$ is a chi-squared rv on $n$ degrees of freedom, so can be expressed as $R^2  = n+\sqrt{2n} Q$ where $Q$ is tight.  So the squared distance converges in distribution to the constant $2$.

This phenomenon is well known, and has a slogan: in high dimensions, almost all pairs of unit vectors are almost orthogonal.